# Disabling submit button until all fields have values on multi-part form

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyup

I have created a multi-part form and need to validate completed fields in visible fieldsets on the form. If all required fields are completed, the the next step button will be enabled.

So Far I have played with a few options none of which are 100% effective

HTML:

```
<div id="set1">
  <fieldset>
  <div>
    <label>field 1</label>
    <input name="f1" type="text" /><br />
    <span class="error"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>field 2</label>
    <input name="f2" type="text" /><br />
  </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
<div id="set2">
  <fieldset>
  <div>
    <label>field 3</label>
    <input name="f3" type="text" /><br />
    <span class="error"></span>
  </div>
  .
  .
  .
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$input = $('fieldset:visible div:has(span[class="error"]) input');
$next = $('fieldset:visible .button');
$input.keyup(function() {
  $input.each(function() {
    var trigger = false;
    $input.each(function() {
      if (!$(this).val()) {
        trigger = true;
      }
    });
    trigger ? $next.attr('class', 'disable') : $next.removeAttr('class');                           
  });
});
```

Could someone help me understand what I am doing wrong? It appears the keyup event is not firing.

Answer (score 0):

You should use jQuery validator. It will make your life a lot easier:

[jQuery Validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)

Comment: I am well aware of that, but am unable to use it on this project. My validation is working, I am just having issues detecting the field state, completed or incomplete per panel.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, the keyup event will be fired, don't worry. Second thing, there is a heavy error at line `if (!$(this).val()) {` This spelling caused by wrong thinking in standard javascript. Translated to it you wanted to test if the value exists or not. The truth is, the value does always exists. It is just "" or a real value.

Look at [my example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZSKJD/1/). After some corrections it works as you wanted, hopefully.

Comment: with a little tweaking here and there, looks like I have the triggers working now, but it seems Ive run into a new issue. My for contains two types of form elements, select and input. bind these events produces seperate results. Do you know of any method of binding these or at least creating a relationship between them - [example](http://jsfiddle.net/designmode/Jb7pg/10/) .

Comment: Without any code I can just guess. Guessing a solution is not the best way. Can you make a working example iof your current code at jsfiddle.net?

Comment: i provided one in my previous comment "example". Here is a [work demo](http://jsfiddle.net/designmode/Jb7pg/10/)

Comment: Based on your next work demo, what is the background for seperating the first object queries and the queries in the variable 'panel'?

Comment: this is just a basic illustration/snapshot of a small portion of my form. The First panel typically would have fields attached as the the second does. I am trying to produce a scalable solution that doesnt nessecarily rely on named elements. I have ammended the working example provided previously to shed a little more light on the situation.

Comment: So I'm back. Can you restore your work demo? I want try to find a solution for you.

Comment: I tried a couple of different ways, but finaly I found a solution. Hopefully it will help. Honestly I'm not really satisfied with it, and yet does work. The solution can see here http://jsfiddle.net/reporter/X5sVt/